# Calculating running time for several macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using the following code to determine the time which it takes for a certain macro to run.

```
    Sub Timer ()

        Dim StartTime As Double
        Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

        StartTime = Timer


        'Some macro executed


        SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

        MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

    End Sub
```

Now, I want to use this timer for several macros which are executed in a row using a button. I'm looking for something like:

```
    <Button>

        'Dim StartTime As Double
        'Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

        StartTime = Timer


        Macro1
        Macro2
        Macro3


        SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

        MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

    <Button>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to report overall time or time for individual macros?

Comment: Overall time for all macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call your macros from within your main timer code

```
Sub Timer ()

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

    StartTime = Timer


    call Macro1()
    call Macro2()
    call Macro3()


    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

If you wanted to know how long each one took individually just declare a SecondsElapsed variable for each Macro and populate it after each Call statement.